# How to return NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a codewars problem-here's the question:

-Write a function that accepts two integers and returns the remainder of dividing the larger value by the smaller value.
-Division by zero should return NaN.

I have the first part figured out, but how do I return NaN if I divide by 0? I don't know a lot about NaN and I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

```
function remainder(n, m){
  if (n > m) {
    let answer = n % m;
    if (m === 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    else {
      return answer;
    }
  }
  else if (m > n) {
    let answer = m % n;
    if (n === 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    else {
      return answer;
    }
  }
  else {
    let answer = n % m;
    return answer;
  }
}
```

Edit: solved, answer is below

Comment: The value `NaN` is a native value in js, you can just use the instruction `return NaN`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Your code returns `undefined` in the case that `n == m`.

Comment: *I've tried setting the variable nan equal to "", undefined, and NaN, but that didn't work.* can you show how setting `nan` to `NaN` didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer (with help from the comments on my question), and it worked. Thank you for your help!

```
function remainder(n, m){
  if (n > m) {
    let answer = n % m;
    if (m === 0) {
      return NaN;
    }
    else {
      return answer;
    }
  }
  else if (m > n) {
    let answer = m % n;
    if (n === 0) {
      return NaN;
    }
    else {
      return answer;
    }
  }
  else {
    let answer = n % m;
    return answer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to our community!

NaN stands for Not-a-Number and it is a property of the global object(in order to understand more about the global object, I would recommend reading about [Scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)).

You could access `NaN` like this:

```
window.NaN => from a browser
Number.NaN
NaN
```

If you want to check if a number is NaN you could use: `isNaN`.

If you want to use it in a function you can just do

```
    function test(x){
      if(isNaN(x)){
        return NaN;
      }
      return x;
    }
```

To come back to your problem, you could do something like this:

```
    function calculateRemainder(a,b){
      return a>b ? a % b : b % a
    }
```

Where `%` is known as the `remainder` operator about which you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder). This operator returns `NaN` if you try to divide by `0` or to operate with `Infinity`.

The following operations return `NaN`:

```
NaN % 2
Infinity % 0
10 % 0
Infinity % Infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that % is not the divider syntax, but this is `/`.

I created a basic example for you:
In this example, the console logs `"divider is 0"`

```js
function divider(up, down) {
  if (down == 0) {
    console.log("divider is 0");
    return NaN
  } else {
    console.log(up / down);
  }
}

divider(5, 0);
```

But here, it will log `2.5`

```
function divider(up, down) {
  if (down == 0) {
    console.log("divider is 0");
    return NaN
  } else {
    console.log(up / down);
  }
}

divider(5, 2);
```